# Estou tentando fazer uma validação no laravel mas não está indo

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Quando deixo os campos do formulário de cadastro sem preencher, são exibidas as mensagens de regras.

Este é o código de cadastro de clientes:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use \App\Clientes;
use Validator; // Validação
use App\Http\Requests\ClienteRules;// Regras do formulário

class VendedorController extends Controller
{
    public function cadastrar(ClienteRules $request){
    $cliente = new \App\Clientes();
    $cliente->nome = $request->nome;
    $cliente->descricao = $request->descricao;
    $cliente->vendedor = $request->vendedor;
    $cliente->orcamento = $request->orcamento;
    $cliente->save();
    return redirect()->to('/lista_Cliente');

}
```

E aqui as requests

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ClienteRules extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'nome' => 'required',
            'descricao' => 'required',
            'vendedor' => 'required',
            'orcamento' => 'required'
        ];
    }
    public function messages(){
        return[
            'nome.required' => 'Informe seu nome.',
            'descricao.required' => 'Informe a descrição do produto.',
            'vendedor.required' => 'Informe o nome do vendedor.',
            'orcamento.required' => 'Informe o orçamento.'

        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver. Na real não tava dando problema, eu só não tava exibindo as mensagens de error no create.blade.php .

```
@if(isset($errors) && count ($errors)>0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
          <p>{{$error}}</p>                 
        @endforeach
    </div>
  @endif
```